# Set the bubble color on a bubble chart based on the value

Tags: javascript

I have to set the colors of each bubble on a bubble chart based on the number that I have on  my array. The only thing that I know is:

- If the value is equal to **3**, the color has to be **"#a68500"**
- If the value is equal to **0**, the color has to be **"#fff79b"**

So, if one element of the array has the value "2.5" I have to find a color that represents that number in the color scale.

I'm using dojox.charting, but I have no idea how create a function that, based on the value, returns the color.

Any idea will be helpful!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getInterpolation(x, min1, max1, min2, max2) {
    return Math.round(x/(max1-min1)*(max2-min2)+min2);    
}
```

Use this like `getInterpolation(2.5, 0, 3, 0xff, 0xa6);` for each RGB component. If you use this frequently in loop you can change min and max to some const values.

Answer (score 2):

So here I think you are going to want to do some percentage based math on the numerical rgb values.  If you have rgb to hex functions available, take advantage of them, if not:

```
var r,g,b,rgb = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})?$/i.exec(color);

if( rgb.length == 5 ) { //argb hex format
    r = parseInt(rgb[2], 16);
    g = parseInt(rgb[3], 16);
    b = parseInt(rgb[4], 16);
    }
else {
    r = parseInt(rgb[1], 16);
    g = parseInt(rgb[2], 16);
    b = parseInt(rgb[3], 16);
}
```

So for r: 0 is ff and 3 is a6, you'll convert to 0:255 and 3:166 which would put 2.5 at ~181
To get back to Hex to would do `181.toString(16);`